Is there a cryptographic method that can only decrypt for a certain range of seeds?
When deriving user_key from master_key as shown below, specify the decryptable range.
And user_key should only be able to decrypt ciphertexts encrypted within that range.
I'm wondering if this method is cryptographically feasible, and if so, what such an algorithm would be called?
master_key

user_key = KeyDerivation(master_key, 200)

ciphertext_100 = Encrypt(master_key, 100, data)
ciphertext_150 = Encrypt(master_key, 150, data)
ciphertext_300 = Encrypt(master_key, 300, data)

Decrypt(user_key, ciphertext_100) => success
Decrypt(user_key, ciphertext_150) => success
Decrypt(user_key, ciphertext_300) => failed
```


Yes, that's possible.
There's an easy solution where ciphertext size increases as the product of plaintext size and number of users: we make a derived key per user, the plaintext is encrypted for each user authorized to decrypt, and the results concatenated to form the complete ciphertext.
But there also are solutions with ciphertext size independent of number of users, assuming the number of users has a known-in-advance upper bound $b$, so that user numbers are in $[0,b]$ (e.g. $b=999$ for at-most 3-digits user number).
Let $c=E(k,d)$ and $d=D(k,c)$ be encryption and decryption per a symmetric authenticated cipher with 256-bit key as the first parameter, e.g. AES-256-GCM.
Let $H(x)$ be the SHA-256 hash of $x$. Define $H^0(x)=x$, and $H^n(x)=H(H^{(n-1)}(x))$ for $n>0$ (that is $H^n(x)$ is $x$ iteratively hashed $n$ times).
Define $\operatorname{KeyDerivation}(k,i)\;=\;i\mathbin\|H^{(b-i)}(k)$
Define $\operatorname{Encrypt}(k,j,d)=j\mathbin\|E(H^{(b-j)}(k),d)$
Define $\operatorname{Decrypt}(i\mathbin\|h,j\mathbin\|c)=D(H^{(i-j)}(h),c)$
Decryption is possible only when $i\ge j$, as asked. It works because encryption is with key $H^{(b-j)}(k)$, decryption is with key $H^{(i-j)}(H^{(b-i)}(k))$, and these two keys are equal.

In a variant, we don't convey $i$ and $j$ in user_key and ciphertext; rather, $\operatorname{Decrypt}(h,c)$ attempts decryption as $D(H^n(h),c)$ for $n$ from $0$ to $b-1$, until one succeeds, which is when $n=i-j$. But computation effort increases near proportionally to plaintext size.

That technique of iteratively derived keys of decreasing power is called ratcheting. When used for symmetric encryption keys between two users in order to prevent compromise of past messages in the event of key compromise (forward secrecy), this is sometime called a symmetric ratchet or symmetric-key ratchet, and crypto folklore since the 1990's or earlier. Here I use it to derive keys for users of ranked trust. I can't recall where I met the concept.

Very cool! Thank you :)
